# Tem como fazer script auto executável em Python? (Autorun)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Olá, eu estou começando a aprender Python, sei somente o básico do básico, queria fazer um script auto executável (autorun), mas porém procurei por toda a internet e não achei em lugar algum como fazer um autorun em Python, então, existe alguma maneira de fazer isso? Se sim, alguém poderia explicar como e deixar um código de exemplo pra mim ver como funciona? Desde já agradeço pela resposta

Aliás, de preferência quero em Python 3

Comment: Pode definir o que é um script auto executável?

Comment: Seria por exemplo, um script já depois de compilado, que se inicia automaticamente, quando eu plugo um Pen drive na máquina por exemplo

Comment: depende do sistema operacional, mas em todo o caso esse script vai precisar ser um serviço que executa quando ocorre tal evento no sistema operacional. No caso vai precisar achar uma biblioteca que faça isso e transformar seu script em um serviço.

Comment: Ah entendi, talvez seja mais fácil então eu partir pelo Java

Answer (score -1):

Uma das opções seria utilizar um Job Scheduler, resumidamente ele vai agendar uma tarefa(job) e quando chegar sua hora, vai ser executa, podendo repetir ou não, depende de como agendou a tarefa(job).

Ex de uma lib:

```
import schedule
import time

def job():
    print("I'm working...")

schedule.every(10).minutes.do(job)
schedule.every().hour.do(job)
schedule.every().day.at("10:30").do(job)
schedule.every(5).to(10).minutes.do(job)
schedule.every().monday.do(job)
schedule.every().wednesday.at("13:15").do(job)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

[Tenha um introdução geral sobre.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Job_scheduler)

[schedule - Python job scheduling for humans.](https://github.com/dbader/schedule)

[Uma lista deles implementados em python](https://github.com/vinta/awesome-python#job-scheduler)